# USB Hard drive mounting as Read-Only

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I've been mounting it with `sudo mount -t ntfs -o umask=000 /dev/sda1 "/media/My Book"` but for some reason it now says `mount: warning: /media/My Book/ seems to be mounted read-only` when I do so, and `ls -l` shows it's correct. The drive has its own power supply and it works fine with my laptop, so I think the problem must be with the Pi. What am I doing wrong?

Update: Just to be clear, that command used to work, and it's read-only for EVERYONE, even root:

```
$ ls -l /media
total 8
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 28 11:11 My Book
```

The contents appear the same way.

Update 2: Probably found the cause. From `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 17 19:37:52 raspberrypi kernel: [   64.688724] NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/W MODULE].
May 17 19:37:52 raspberrypi kernel: [   65.195397] NTFS volume version 3.1.
May 17 19:37:52 raspberrypi kernel: [   65.195439] NTFS-fs error (device sda1): load_system_files(): Volume is dirty.  Mounting read-only.  Run chkdsk and mount in Windows.
```

Probably should've tried looking there before...

Answer (score 3):

`ntfs` is a kernel-based, read-only ntfs driver (actually you can modify a file or its attributes, but not its size).

Try `mount -t ntfs-3g`, which relies on `fuse` (Filesystem in USErspace).

Comment: `mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'` According to a comment on [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/589763/how-to-mount-an-ntfs-filesystem-allowing-all-users-full-access) the `ntfs` option uses `ntfs-3g`. And the commanad I listed used to work...but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Running `chkdsk E: /F` on Windows fixed it.

Answer (score -3):

@Zelda64fan You need to install this ntfs-3g module on your distro to make it work.

Comment: You should expand your answer to include how to install the module and why you believe that will fix the problem. if you read the other comments and answers I don't think your suggestion is the answer tot he OP's question.

Comment: The OP answered his own question, so you should update your answer to show how to figure out what to do and how to do it.